# How do I get the Debian installer to require a specific OS version?

Tags: debian, debian-packaging

I'm trying to help my installer team find an answer to this issue:

We have 2 Debian installers for Ubuntu. Let's say one requires Ubuntu 20.0.4 and the other is for a range of previous versions. Is there a way to force each installer notify the user  that they are using the wrong version of our installer on the wrong OS?  I saw a preinst script or a controller section but no clear way to specify the OS version that the installer is valid for.

Currently we get an 'unmet dependencies' message which doesn't describe the issue.  We don't want the user to use -f to force the dependencies as installing older components is not generally a good idea.

Comment: "preinst" script is probably best place to notify the user that they are using the wrong installer. it will be run by package manager even before unpacking

Comment: This was taking so long that I spoke with the actual Debian team.  They stated that the pre install script is NOT run before installer checks requirements so the error would still occur.  It is simple to test I'll have the installer team check it out by printing something to the screen.  If the pre install text comes out first where good.  It would also have to be able to cancel the process.

Comment: you can still do it preinst script..if  in same script you can check for dependencies yourself and trigger install if needed and move all your dependencies out of PreDepends/Depends from control file.... maybe you can put it in suggests/recommends

Comment: That would be great but everything that we have is required and without the dependencies we won't run.  Things like networking is kind of important.  The installer guys suggested making an installer that requires our current installer.  Which would allow the preinstall to work.  It's wacky but we'll test it all out.  Still think this installer should have fields for start and end OS versions.  Such a basic thing to have the installer NOT have.